# Normal Basis for Galois extension $ \Bbb K / \Bbb F$ implies $ \Bbb K=\Bbb F(a)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Normal Basis for Galois extension $ \Bbb K / \Bbb F$ is defined as looking at $\Bbb K$ as a vector space over $\Bbb F $ with the basis of $(\sigma(a)| \sigma \in Gal(\Bbb K / \Bbb F))$ for $a \in \Bbb K$

I need to proof that $ \Bbb K=\Bbb F(a)$

I know that Galois group is acting transitively on the roots of the minimal separable and normal polynomial over $\Bbb K$:
$f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n (x-\sigma_i(a))$

How I proof that for every i, $\sigma_i(a)=a^k $ for some $k \in \Bbb N$?

Comment: It is not true that $\sigma_i(a) = a^k$ for some $k$; nearly everything is a counterexample to that.

Comment: Any thoughts on my answer, Daniel?

Comment: Earth to Daniel, come in, please.

Comment: I agree it may be any structure with the binary action on $\alpha$ such that $\sigma_i(a)=a^3-a$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the conjugates of $\alpha$ form a basis for the extension, then the number of conjugates must equal the degree of the extension, so the degree of $\alpha$ must equal the degree of the extension, so then degree of $F(\alpha)$ over $F$ must equal the degree of the extension, so $F(\alpha)=K$.